# Ubuntu: /proc/pid/comm file missing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proc

On my development box, under `/proc/[pid]/` there is a file called `comm` containing the name of the executable for that process. I use this to validate the process to which I am sending a signal. On our live server it does not exist. Both machines are running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (albeit the live server is virtualised). On the live machine the executable exists in `cmdline` but of course with command line arguments which have to be parsed out. Why does one instance have `comm` and not the other?

Comment: Are both machines running the stock Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: I am starting to suspect that this is a 2.6 vs. 3.x issue since the virtualised server instance reports the 2.6.32 kernel and my development machine is running 3.2.0-55. I would like to know for sure though. In both cases `/etc/issue` reports the same OS.

Comment: For reference and clarification, 7 years later, you had an off-by-one "error" - `man 5 proc` documents that `/proc/[pid]/comm` is "since Linux 2.6.33" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that your virtual machine's kernel is either too old or not configured to provide the `/proc/PID/comm` file.

According to the proc(5) man page, you may be able to use the second field in `/proc/[pid]/stat`. It is described as:

> The filename of the executable, in parentheses.  This is visible whether or not the executable is swapped out.

The name of the command may be truncated if it is longer than 16 characters.

Comment: I think this must be what's going on. I ended up using `comm` if it exists and falling back to parsing `cmdline` if not. I'm accepting this as best answer.